# Get current Week of the Month as a Number

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I get the current week of the month as a number in Dart? I need to create some sort of calender with a week view where it says something like "2. Week of January"

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have the same question now))

Answer (score 5):

My Answer is impaired from @dblank answer

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  int get weekOfMonth {
    var date = this;
    final firstDayOfTheMonth = DateTime(date.year, date.month, 1);
    int sum = firstDayOfTheMonth.weekday - 1 + date.day;
    if (sum % 7 == 0) {
      return sum ~/ 7;
    } else {
      return sum ~/ 7 + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var wom = DateTime.now().weekOfMonth;
```

Comment: today 2023.04.07 results to be the seccond Friday of the month with this code

Comment: This answer is for the calendar, where the week begins on Monday.

Answer (score 3):

You can use DateTime().now() to get the current time and date of the system or today's date also. Here is the code snippet below:

```
// Current date and time of system
  String date = DateTime.now().toString();

// This will generate the time and date for first day of month
  String firstDay = date.substring(0, 8) + '01' + date.substring(10);

// week day for the first day of the month
  int weekDay = DateTime.parse(firstDay).weekday;

  DateTime testDate = DateTime.now();

  int weekOfMonth;

//  If your calender starts from Monday
  weekDay--;
  weekOfMonth = ((testDate.day + weekDay) / 7).ceil();
  print('Week of the month: $weekOfMonth');
  weekDay++;

// If your calender starts from sunday
  if (weekDay == 7) {
    weekDay = 0;
  }
  weekOfMonth = ((testDate.day + weekDay) / 7).ceil();
  print('Week of the month: $weekOfMonth');
```

Alternatively, if are looking for a complete implementation of the calender month UI then [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59842498/how-do-i-build-this-layout-ui-in-flutter/59849512#59849512)

Comment: What to do if calender starts from monday

Comment: I have updated the answer and added the code to handle both kinds of situations as well. You will find your answer in the updated code.

Answer (score 2):

```dart
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  int get weekOfMonth {
    var wom = 0;
    var date = this;

    while (date.month == month) {
      wom++;
      date = date.subtract(const Duration(days: 7));
    }

    return wom;
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
var wom = DateTime.now().weekOfMonth;
```

Comment: Hi, @dblank is this code tested in production. I can't find any bug here but It would be great to know if it is tested. Thanks

Comment: if the month starts on saturday this will give the wrong answer from the 3rd date