# How do I build this layout/UI in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a calendar for my app and for this,and while I can just use a plugin, i've chosen not to, and I decided to implement it myself. I've chosen this approach: I have a list of text widgets that go from Monday to Sunday

```
    List<Widget> days = [
  Text("Sun"),Text("Mon")....Text("Sat")
];
```

Next, I have several lists of all the weekdays

```
    List<Widget> mon = []; 
    List<Widget> tue = [];

 // and so on
```

Now, i this have method that loops through all the days in the given month, and stores the week days in their respective list. i.e,it would store 1 in wed list, 2 in thurs list (for this month) like so:

```
void populateCalendar(){
    final dateToday =  DateTime.now();
    final DateTime lastDay = Utils.lastDayOfMonth(dateToday);


    for(int i=1;i<=lastDay.day;i++){
      var date = new DateTime.utc(dateToday.year,dateToday.month,i);

      if(date.weekday == 1){
        mon.add(FlatButton(onPressed: null, child: Text(date.day.toString())));

      }
      else if(date.weekday == 2){
        tue.add(FlatButton(onPressed: null, child: Text(date.day.toString())));

      }

      else if(date.weekday == 3){
        wed.add(FlatButton(onPressed: null, child: Text(date.day.toString())));

      }
      else if(date.weekday == 4){
        thur.add(FlatButton(onPressed: null, child: Text(date.day.toString())));

      }
      else if(date.weekday == 5){
        fri.add(FlatButton(onPressed: null, child: Text(date.day.toString())));

      }
      else if(date.weekday == 6){
        sat.add(FlatButton(onPressed: null, child: Text(date.day.toString())));

      }
      else if(date.weekday == 7){
        sun.add(FlatButton(onPressed: null, child: Text(date.day.toString())));

      }




    }

  }
```

So the layout i want to achieve is like this: basically i want to display the weekdays like Sun Mon Tues Wed and so on, and underneath each date, i would like to display the list of weekday(like list mon) like this: Sun 
 5
 
 12
  19 .. and so on. Here's a rough sketch
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gridview.builder() to create the UI as you described above.
Here is the code snippet that will handle all work for you, like handling leap year etc.

```
class BuildCalender extends StatelessWidget {
  final month = DateTime.now().month;
  final day = DateTime.now().day;
  final year = DateTime.now().year;
  final days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final start = difference();
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Sun'),
            Text('Mon'),
            Text('Tue'),
            Text('Wed'),
            Text('Thu'),
            Text('Fri'),
            Text('Sat'),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          child: GridView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate:
                SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 7),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (index < start) {
                return Container();
              }
              return Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.4))),
                child: Text('${index + 1 - start}'),
              );
            },
            itemCount: (month == 2
                    ? checkYear(year) ? days[month - 1] + 1 : days[month - 1]
                    : days[month - 1]) +
                start,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  int difference() {
    String date = DateTime.now().toString();
    String firstDay = date.substring(0, 7) + '01' + date.substring(10);
    int weekDay = DateTime.parse(firstDay).weekday;
    if (weekDay == 7) {
      return 0;
    }
    return weekDay;
  }

  bool checkYear(int year) {
    if (year % 400 == 0) return true;
    if (year % 100 == 0) return false;
    if (year % 4 == 0) return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```